# Avoid CR:LF characters in NGINX

Tags: nginx

I wish to send all urls with CR:LF characters in NGINX to error page. I try to find how to do it, but didn’t see any nginx support for it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CR and LF characters will be encoded as `%0D%0A` in the `$request_uri`.

You could detect them by placing an `if` block near the top of your `server` block:

```
server {
    ...
    if ( $request_uri ~* "%0A|%0D" ) { return 403; }
```

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.